# I am using perl one liner for search replace. I want to replace string with '

Tags: perl

I want to replace string with ' but it is not working.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/assume/assume 3\';/g' abcd
```

It gives error : `Unmatched '`.

Comment: In bash command line you should escape single quote with either `'\''` or `'"'"'`. For example both `echo 'A'\''B'` and `echo 'A'"'"'B'` gives output `A'B`

Comment: In other words, in bash, you can't escape a single quote inside single quotes; you need to close the single quotes, then add a single quote, and start single quotes again.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid shell escape hell, you can use `\x27` instead of `'`

```
perl -p -i -e 's/assume/assume 3\x27;/g'
```